# Should view actions and event methods give the same result?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to detect events on table cells. I have found that I can receive the events when I use the {{action}} helper, but not when I define an event method on the view. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9nWNQ/1/

Clicking the text "No action" should log a message, but it doesn't.

You might ask why I don't just use the action? The problem is that I want to detect multiple events and according to https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/569 I need to use a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but if you define your view as a  by setting `tagName: 'tr'`, it seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/ACzrY/#base

Perhaps your code produce an invalid html page, and the the click event is not triggered

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/pX8ww/

I've replace the view tag with 'td' to behave more like the example

Comment: I think the HTML in my original code is correct, and the HTML from your code is incorrect - but it could be that events can only be attached to rows and not cells.

Comment: In your code, when you want to insert an ember view in a <tr> tag, you are inserting a <div>. Is <table><tr><div><td> a valid table definition ? I don't think so. And if you look the produced code, the ember-view is then misplaced. Anyway, I've updated my code, is it good for you now ?